# Phonetic sound of Uzziah

Tags: old-testament

I am searching for a bible character whose name starts with the short u or /ʌ/ sound for my project. Can I use the name Uzziah? Or is there any other bible character whose name has the short u or /ʌ/ sound. Please advise.

I am so glad to have found this site.

Comment: Hi and welcome! If you haven't already, please consider taking the [tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) and browsing the [help centre](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) to find out how we do things around here. I'm not sure that this site is the best place for a question like this & whether it will be even considered on-topic here, but it certainly doesn't help to try. Have you seen [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_biblical_names_starting_with_U) yet? From my limited understanding most of those names use either the 'Yoo' or 'oo' sounds (including Uzziah).

Comment: Some of these ones are probably closer to starting with the short u: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_biblical_names_starting_with_A

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about the pronunciation of names.

Comment: Uzzah and Uzziah are probably your best bets. Be aware, though, that in Hebrew they are pronounced with a "u" as in "blue," not with a "u" as in "hug" as in English.

Comment: Welcome to the site. We're also glad you found it. This site is mostly designed to handle questions about Christianity, as in, the dogma and practice of it's various different believers. It will probably be put on hold. Please see the [Types of questions that are within community guidelines](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3409). I hope to see you post again soon.

Comment: I actually asked this question in the English stack exchange but they put me on hold as answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific experts.  I was so happy to find this site and I get the same response? Please don't do that.

Comment: Lee Woofendon.  You are right about the fact that in Hebrew they are usually pronounced as "u" as in blue.  Heard the name read out in the Hebrew audio bible as that.  Now my problem is to find another bible character, story or place that has the short "u" sound  as in hug.  Any suggestions?  Tks!

Answer (score 4):

There are these three other biblical names with the short u or /ʌ/ sound ( and all has a beautiful meaning):

[Uzziel](http://org)

[Uriah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uriah)

[Uriel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uriel)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uzziel